# Why use Array's +: and padTo will get the result as ArraySeq

Tags: scala

My code is as below, I need to prepend `h1` before the recursive result.

If I change the line with the comment to `getLCSArray(...).+:(h1)`,  I will get an build error with a type mismatch.

I checked the API docs for `Array`'s `+:` and its result should be `Array` too. If I use `toArray` to change the type back to `Array`, I get the error "No ClassTag available for G".

My Scala version is 2.10.6

So I had 2 questions:

1. Why do `+:` and `padTo` return `ArraySeq`?
2. How can I change `ArraySeq` back to `Array` with a generic type `G`?

---

```
error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[G]
[INFO]  required: Array[G]
[INFO]                 case true => getLCSArray(a1.tail,a2.tail).+:(h1)
[ERROR] one error found
```

The code can been compiled, but the logic is wrong.

```
def getLCSArray[G>:Equals](a1: Array[G], a2: Array[G]): Array[G] =
  (a1.isEmpty,a2.isEmpty) match {
    case (true,_) => a1
    case (_,true) => a2
    case (_,_) => {
      val h1 = a1.head
      val h2 = a2.head
      h1 == h2 match {
        case true => getLCSArray(a1.tail ,a2.tail) // this line is wrong
        case _ => longest(getLCSArray(a1.tail, a2), getLCSArray(a1, a2.tail))
      }
    }
  }

def longest[G>:Equals](a1: Array[G], a2: Array[G]): Array[G] = {
  val length1 = a1.length
  val length2 = a2.length
  length1 > length2 match {
    case true => a1
    case _ => a2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `ClassTag` to create a new array of the correct element type.

In the ScalaDoc, consult the "full signature" below the method documentation to see that the result of `+:` depends on the `CanBuildFrom` implicit that is selected. The `[use case]` signature (that comes first) confuses everybody.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def getLCSArray[G>:Equals : reflect.ClassTag](a1:Array[G],a2:Array[G]):Array[G]=
    (a1.isEmpty,a2.isEmpty) match {
    case (true,_) => a1
    case (_,true) => a2
    case (_,_)=>{
        val h1=a1.head
        val h2=a2.head
        h1 == h2 match {
            case true => h1 +: getLCSArray(a1.tail,a2.tail)
            case _ => longest(getLCSArray(a1.tail,a2),getLCSArray(a1,a2.tail))
        }

    }
}
def longest[G>:Equals](a1:Array[G],a2:Array[G]):Array[G]={
    val length1 = a1.length
    val length2 = a2.length
    length1 > length2 match {
        case true => a1
        case _ => a2
    }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

getLCSArray: [G >: Equals](a1: Array[G], a2: Array[G])(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[G])Array[G]
longest: [G >: Equals](a1: Array[G], a2: Array[G])Array[G]
```